# SPARQL Filter language for only one property

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

```
SELECT ?pt ?vl
WHERE {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Havana_Storm> ?pt ?vl.}
```

My query will return list of property-value pairs of this book; but with the "abstract" property, I only want to take English language. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

This filters all values to the English language.

```
SELECT ?pt ?vl
WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Havana_Storm> ?pt ?vl.
    FILTER(LANG(?vl) = "en")
}
```

[SPARQL Query](http://yasgui.org/short/OELpGV01z)

Comment: It will delete all of the properties which does not have a language tag. Thank your reply.